# Node.js version not correct?

Tags: node.js

I just downloaded node.js via their website and found that the version I had on my local machine was way outdated (v5.11pre). So, seeing that there was a 10.2 version out, I decided to completely uninstall node.js from my machine and reinstall the latest and greatest version!

After going through the steps to install everything I ran the following command and found out something strange:

```
$ node --version
v0.5.11-pre
```

Can someone explain why the tarball for node 10.2 just installed a extremely old version of node? Also, how can I get the newest version!?

EDIT:

If it helps, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the correct version was installed indeed, but your path still points to the old installation.

Comment: hmmm ok. how exactly do I remove the old pointer? is this just in my $PATH variable, or another path?